# Use grouped_collection_select to group a model by enum

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, enums

Say I have two classes

```
class Recording
  belongs_to :conversation
end

class Conversation < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :recordings

  enum status: [ :active, :archived ]
end
```

And I want to select the conversation stored on the 'Recording' model. How can I use grouped_collection_select to group all of the records in the `Conversation` table by the two enums, `active` and `archived` in this case?

All of the examples I can find about grouped_collection_select refer to calling method on members to provide a collection; versus grouping an existing collection.

Comment: all of the records in the Conversation table, not  the Conversations of a recording?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `grouped_collection_select` method is not the best tool for your needs because it really deals with associated records of a main record, whereas you, if I understand correctly, simply want to add all `Conversation` records to a select tag, but grouped by its *attribute*, not association.

You can easily construct the grouped options manually, though. I'd put this code into a helper not to clutter the view template too much:

```
# app/helpers/conversations_helper.rb
module ConversationsHelper

  def grouped_conversations_options_for_select(selected_conversation_id = nil)
    options = {}
    Conversation.statuses.keys.each do |status|
      options[status] = Conversation.with_status(status).pluck(:name, :id)
    end
    grouped_options_for_select(options, selected_conversation_id)
  end

end

# app/view/show.html.erb
<%= select_tag :conversation_id, grouped_conversations_options_for_select(params[:conversation_id]) %>
```

The helper first constructs a hash with the following structure:

```
{
  active:   [[ conversation.id, conversation.name ], [...]],
  archived: [[ conversation.id, conversation.name ], [...]],
}
```

This hash can be then passed to the [`grouped_options_for_select`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper.html#method-i-grouped_options_for_select) which converts it to the `<OPTIONS>` tags including proper `<OPTGROUP>` tags. The helper also supports setting the currently selected value in the select options. Its output is then passed to the select tag in the view template.

For the helper to work, you also need to add the following scope to the `Conversation` model:

```
# app/models/conversation.rb
scope :with_status, ->(status) { where(status: statuses[status]) }
```

Comment: Even before you answered, that's pretty much what I ended up doing. Thanks!