# Using model constants as groups in Rails grouped_collection_select

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, drop-down-menu

I'm building a form where users create a financial transaction. One field is a drop down list of bank accounts.

I would like this dropdown list to group all listed Bank Accounts by each account's account type (BankAccount::ACCOUNT_TYPE - an attribute in each BankAccount record).

If I manually code everything right now, the code would look like this:

```
<%= f.select :bank_account_id,
    {
      'On-Budget' => ['Cash',
                     'Credit Card 1',
                     'Credit Card 2',
                     'Venmo'],
      'Off-Budget' => ['Investment Bank 1',
                     'Investment Bank 1'],
      'Closed' => ['Old Bank 1',
                     'Old Bank 2'],
    }   %>
```

[image: grouped drop down list]

app/models/bank_account.rb - where I define ACCOUNT_TYPES

```
class BankAccount < ApplicationRecord
ACCOUNT_TYPES = %w(On-Budget Off-Budget Closed).freeze
...
end
```

Here is my working collection.select, without grouping

```
<%= f.collection_select :bank_account_id, 
                        BankAccount.all, 
                        :id, 
                        :name, 
                        {prompt: 'Select an account'} %>
```

From the rails API, I think grouped_collection_select is what I need
(https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormBuilder.html#method-i-grouped_collection_select)

```
grouped_collection_select(method, collection, group_method, group_label_method, option_key_method, option_value_method, options = {}, html_options = {})
```

Using `BankAccount::ACCOUNT_TYPES` as my group_method, and group_label_method doesn't work.

```
<%= f.grouped_collection_select(:bank_account_id,
                                BankAccount.all,
                                BankAccount::ACCOUNT_TYPES, (group_method?)
                                BankAccount::ACCOUNT_TYPEs, (group_label_method?)
                                :id,
                                :name,
                                {prompt: 'Select an account' } %>
```

Comment: Refer this gist https://gist.github.com/tessi/5505930 for more info on `grouped_collection_select`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer from this SO question: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36854817/use-grouped-collection-select-to-group-a-model-by-enum](https://%3C%25=%20select_tag%20:bank_account_id,%20grouped_bank_account_options_for_select(params%5B:bank_account_id%5D),%20%7Bprompt:%20%27Select%20an%20account%27%7D%20%25%3E)

I created a helper method

```
def grouped_bank_account_options_for_select(selected_bank_account_id = nil)
    options = {}
    BankAccount::ACCOUNT_TYPES.each do |t|
      unless t == "Closed"
        options[t] = BankAccount.where(account_type: t)
                                .pluck(:name, :id)
      end
    end
    grouped_options_for_select(options, selected_bank_account_id)
  end
```

and then called it in the view's form helper

```
<%= select_tag :bank_account_id, grouped_bank_account_options_for_select(params[:bank_account_id]), {prompt: 'Select an account'} %>
```